# CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified in Roo

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-roo

Iam I tried to run my first Roo application using Roo Shell commands.But then when I attempt to perform tests it errors out with

```
CreateProcess error=2,The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I checked and my `PATH` variable is set to the below.Is there something else I'm doing wrong ?

> PATh
>   :=C:\SpringSource\springsource\spring-roo-1.2.2.RELEASE\bin;C:\SpringSource\springsource\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;

Comment: could you post the full error message

Answer (score 4):

That error message usually has the name of the command it can't find preceding it.  Check if that command is in your path.